# What is a Lambda Calculus equivalent of the map function in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, lambda-calculus, map-function

The map function returns a list constructed by applying a function (the first argument) to all items in a list passed as the second argument.

I'm trying to figure out what this would look like if displayed in Lambda Calculus notation. Can anyone give an example?

Comment: There are many online writeups of the lambda calculus which cover this. https://jwodder.freeshell.org/lambda.html is one example I found. I don't see any reason to re-cover this ground on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged `haskell` I'll write the answer in Haskell, but building everything on functions like you would in lambda calculus. This generally incurs carrying around an extra type parameter `r` for the continuation-passing style.

Lists <del>are usually</del> can be encoded as deconstruction-matchers: (this is *Scott encoding*, as the comments inform me)

```
newtype List r a = List { deconstructList
             :: r                    -- ^ `Nil` case
             -> (a -> List r a -> r) -- ^ `Cons` case
             -> r                    -- ^ result
           }
```

Now we want to give this a `Functor` instance. As with other problems, you can let the compiler guide you:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List _
```

This will prompt

```
LambdaList.hs:8:26: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: r -> (b -> List r b -> r) -> r
      Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
               at LambdaList.hs:8:3-6
             ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at LambdaList.hs:7:10-25
    • In the first argument of ‘List’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: List _
      In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (List l) = List _
    • Relevant bindings include
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
          (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:3)
      Valid hole fits include
        const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
          with const @r @(b -> List r b -> r)
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at LambdaList.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’))
        return :: forall (m :: * -> *) a. Monad m => a -> m a
          with return @((->) (b -> List r b -> r)) @r
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at LambdaList.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’))
        pure :: forall (f :: * -> *) a. Applicative f => a -> f a
          with pure @((->) (b -> List r b -> r)) @r
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ at LambdaList.hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’))
  |
8 |   fmap f (List l) = List _
  |                          ^
```

So we're supposed to define a function; well then it's probably a good idea to start with lambda-binding some arguments:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List $ \nilCs consCs -> _
```

```
LambdaList.hs:8:45: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: r
      Where: ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at LambdaList.hs:7:10-25
    • In the expression: _
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘\ nilCs consCs -> _’
      In the expression: List $ \ nilCs consCs -> _
    • Relevant bindings include
        consCs :: b -> List r b -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:35)
        nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:29)
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
          (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:3)
      Valid hole fits include nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:29)
```

The CPS-result should still come from the original list, so we need to use that at this point – with args still TBD, but the nil case won't change so we can right away pass that too:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List $ \nilCs consCs -> l nilCs _
```

```
LambdaList.hs:8:53: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: a -> List r a -> r
      Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
               at LambdaList.hs:8:3-6
             ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at LambdaList.hs:7:10-25
    • In the second argument of ‘l’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: l nilCs _
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ nilCs consCs -> l nilCs _’
    • Relevant bindings include
        consCs :: b -> List r b -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:35)
        nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:29)
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
          (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:3)
```

So it's again function-time, i.e. bind some arguments:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List
     $ \nilCs consCs -> l nilCs $ \lHead lTail -> _
```

```
LambdaList.hs:9:51: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: r
      Where: ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at LambdaList.hs:7:10-25
    • In the expression: _
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘\ lHead lTail -> _’
      In the expression: l nilCs $ \ lHead lTail -> _
    • Relevant bindings include
        lTail :: List r a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:42)
        lHead :: a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:36)
        consCs :: b -> List r b -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:15)
        nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:9)
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
      Valid hole fits include nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:9)
```

At this point we have a lot in scope that could conceivably be used, but a good rule of thumb is that we should probably use all of them at least once, so let's bring in `consCs`, with two TBD arguments:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List
     $ \nilCs consCs -> l nilCs $ \lHead lTail -> consCs _ _
```

```
LambdaList.hs:9:58: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: b
      Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
               at LambdaList.hs:8:3-6
    • In the first argument of ‘consCs’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: consCs _ _
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ lHead lTail -> consCs _ _’
    • Relevant bindings include
        lTail :: List r a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:42)
        lHead :: a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:36)
        consCs :: b -> List r b -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:15)
        nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:9)
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
```

Ok, there's only one way to obtain a `b` value: using `f`, which needs an `a` as its argument, for which we have exactly one, namely `lHead`:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List
     $ \nilCs consCs -> l nilCs
      $ \lHead lTail -> consCs (f lHead) _
```

```
LambdaList.hs:9:60: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: List r b
      Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> List r a -> List r b
               at LambdaList.hs:8:3-6
             ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at LambdaList.hs:7:10-25
    • In the second argument of ‘consCs’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: consCs _ _
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ lHead lTail -> consCs _ _’
    • Relevant bindings include
        lTail :: List r a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:42)
        lHead :: a (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:36)
        consCs :: b -> List r b -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:15)
        nilCs :: r (bound at LambdaList.hs:9:9)
        l :: r -> (a -> List r a -> r) -> r (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at LambdaList.hs:8:8)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
```

Here we have a bit of a problem: no `List r b` is in scope or in the result of any of the bindings. However, what does yield a `List r b` is the function we're just defining here: `fmap f`. In standard lambda calculus you can't actually recursively call a definition (you need to use a fixpoint combinator to emulate it), but I'll ignore this here. This is a valid Haskell solution:

```
instance Functor (List r) where
  fmap f (List l) = List
     $ \nilCs consCs -> l nilCs
      $ \lHead lTail -> consCs (f lHead) (fmap f lTail)
```

Or written in lambda style (erasing the `List` newtype constructor),

```
map = \f l ν ζ ⟼ l ν (\h t ⟼ ζ (f h) (map f t))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `(a -> r -> r)` instead of `(a -> List a -> r)`? What could `toList [1]` look like, with the latter type? (with the former it's easy,  `List $ \ r c -> c 1 r`)

Comment: The type here is the Scott encoding of lists, the type which uses `(a -> r -> r)` is the church encoding. They're isomorphic, but there are some type-theoretic differences I'm not qualified to explain :)

Comment: @WillNess `toList [1] ≡ List $ \_ c -> c 1 . List $ \r _ -> r`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks, I got that expression too but thought it can't be right since it ignores the first `r` argument supplied to it... (it should be `$` in place of that `.`, I think?) and what could that `c` argument be? `deconstructList (toList [1]) undefined c where c a t = ??` that one I really have no leads on. I thought `c 1 t` would somehow run that `t` with the outer `r` but it can't; after unwrapping that `List $ \r c -> r`, there's no `r` to apply it to. (?) IOW how can we re-create the `[1]` (or any other list) from its `List` equivalent? I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: @oisdk thanks for the info. do you know the answer to my above comment (how to get the original list back from its Scott-encoding `List` equivalent)? (admittedly I haven't yet read through that WP article...)

Comment: @leftaroundabout (scratch that remark about `$` vs `.`, both are of course equivalent)

Comment: @WillNess Here's a gist with conversion functions between church-encoded and scott-encoded lists https://gist.github.com/oisdk/7f9a43d054673cf374eb991aafbfbd95

Comment: @oisdk so, [derived from your code](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/618150921690b390d7ef089d4d3e7beb), `listToScott  =  foldr (\ x r -> Scott $ \ z c -> c x r) (Scott $ \ z c -> z)` and `scottToList (Scott g) = g [] (\ x sc_t -> x : scottToList sc_t)`. Church encoding is a function that *will* `foldr` over the list, and Scott encoding is a *selector* function, created by `foldr`ing the list, which, having received two observers -- each intended for each of the possible data type alternatives -- will call the appropriate observer with its corresponding data from that alternative. :)

Comment: lastly, to answer my own question up above, `deconstructList (toList [..., whatever, ...]) [] c where c a t = a : (deconstructList t [] c)`.

Comment: @WillNess "Church encoding is a function that will foldr over the list, and Scott encoding is a selector function" yes this is exactly correct.