# How to infer the type of the Scott encoded List constructor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types, higher-rank-types, scott-encoding

Scott encoded lists can be defined as followed:

```
newtype List a =
    List {
      uncons :: forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r
    }
```

As opposed to the ADT version `List` is both type and data constructor. Scott encoding determines ADTs through pattern matching, which essentially means removing one layer of constructors. Here is the full `uncons` operation without implicit arguments:

```
uncons :: r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> List a -> r
--    Nil ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cons
uncons nil cons (List f) = f nil cons
```

This makes perfect sense. `uncons` takes a constant, a continuation and a `List` and produces whatever value.

The type of the data constructor, however, doesn't make much sense to me:

```
List :: (forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r) -> List a
```

I see that `r` has its own scope but this isn't very helpful. Why are `r` and `List a` flipped compared to `uncons`? And why are there additional parentheses on the LHS?

I'm probably muddling up type and term level here..

Comment: That's not the type of `uncons`. If you look at its actual type, you see `List` and `uncons` are just inverses (`List :: something -> something else; uncons :: something else -> something`).

Comment: "*Here is the full `uncons` operation without implicit arguments*" - where did you get that from? The "implicit argument" `List a` comes first, and produces the type of the "field".

Comment: I should have called the standalone version `uncons'`. It is not meant to be the written out version of the newtype declaration. I put the `List` argument at the end for convenience. `List`'s type still doesn't make sense to me. It is a type level lambda which takes another type level lambda as an argument and produces a list. I cannot make the connection to the term level.

Comment: @scriptum ??? `forall` has the *syntax* of a type level lambda, but its meaning has *nothing* to do with them. The definition is really just `List a = forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r`. Think about what that latter type means. The two functions replace `=` with `->` and `<-` in turn to form an isomorphism.

Comment: @scriptum I.e. your `uncons` is just the actual `uncons` with flipped arguments. You apply either to a `List` and they give you function of some type. You can take that function and put it back into a `List`. `forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r` is just the type of that function. It *is* `List a`.

Comment: @HTNW Sorry for the confusion. What I didn't understand (and partially still don't) was how to actually use the `List` value constructor given its type. The nil case was simple: `List (\nil cons -> nil)`. But the cons case wasn't: `List (\nil cons) -> cons` doesn't work, because it'd produce an infinite type. `List (\nil cons) -> cons True nil` doesn't work either, because the caller must not decide the type of `r`. I guess this is one of the properties rank-n entails.

Comment: @scriptum In `cons True nil` the second parameter needs to be a list (but `nil` is not a list!). Lists are functions of two parameters `\nil _ -> nil` would be a list. Putting it together results in: `List (\_ cons -> cons True (List (\nil _ -> nil)))`

Comment: [related search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bhaskell%5d%20%22Scott%20encoding%22). [related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63667134/849891) (and the comments under the answer).

Comment: (in particular this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667134/what-is-a-lambda-calculus-equivalent-of-the-map-function-in-haskell/63668681#comment112633064_63668681) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/618150921690b390d7ef089d4d3e7beb#file-oisdk-s-church-scott-hs))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Moved my comment to this answer as requested.)</sup>

Given

```
newtype List a =
    List {
      uncons :: forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r
    }
```

let us write down some lists. Note that lists are essentially functions of two parameters (`\nil cons -> ...`).

```
-- []
empty = List (\nil _ -> nil)

-- [True]
-- True : []
-- (:)  True []
-- cons True nil
list1 = List (\_ cons -> cons True (List (\nil _ -> nil)))

-- [True, False]
-- True : False : []
-- (:)  True ((:)  False [])
-- cons True (cons False nil)
list2 = List (\_ cons -> 
           cons True (List (\_ cons' -> 
               cons' False (List (\nil _ -> nil)))))
```

Comment: My original confusion came from the recursive portion of `List`'s type `List :: (forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r) -> List a`. Consequently I didn't know how to apply the value constructor to create values of type `List something`. As presented in this answer it is actually pretty straightfoward.

Answer (score 4):

What is a `List`?  As you say, it's a thing that, when provided with a constant (what to do if the list is empty) and a continuation (what to do if the list is non-empty), does one of those things.  In types, it takes an `r` and a `a -> List a -> r` and produces an `r`.

So, how do we make a list?  Well, we need the function that underlies this behavior.  That is, we need a function that itself takes the `r` and the `a -> List a -> r` and does something with them (presumably, either returning the `r` directly or calling the function on some `a` and `List a`).  The type of *that* would look something like:

```hs
List :: (r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r) -> List a
--         ^ the function that _takes_ the nil and continuation and does stuff with them
```

But, this isn't *quite* right, which becomes clear if we use explicit `forall`:

```hs
List :: forall a r. (r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r) -> List a
```

Remember, `List` should be able to work for *any* `r`, but with this function, the `r` is actually provided ahead of time.  Indeed, there's nothing wrong with someone specializing this type to, say, `Int`, resulting in:

```hs
List :: forall a. (Int -> (a -> List a -> Int) -> Int) -> List a
```

But this is no good!  This `List` would only ever be able to produce `Int`s!  Instead, we put the `forall` *inside* the first set of parentheses, indicating that the creator of a `List` must provide a function that can work on *any* `r` rather than a particular one.  This yields the type:

```hs
List :: (forall r. r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r) -> List a
```